# In Distribution Mode how to identify at what Number application failed

Tags: jmeter

I have designed the Test in Distribution Mode and When Request Fails Stop the Test

1 Master Machine & 5 Salve Machines per machine with 300 Unique Logins i.e total 1500 Users for 1 Iteration .

Since it's distribution mode let's say test has failed after 10 min's and stopped the test, so how do I identify exactly at what Number Thread / Request has failed. Here The goal is to Identify the  Upper Limit of the application, i.e how many Login's can handle the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you configured JMeter Thread Group to stop after any failure the last line of the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) will contain the number of active users in `allThreads` column.
2. Alternatively you can open the .jtl results file using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)) and see how many users were online during this or that test phase.
3. Also you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of the .jtl results file, it contains comprehensive tables and charts which can help you to analyze your test results.